# Java controllers in Scala project in play framework?

Tags: java, scala, controller, playframework

Is it possible to have both java and scala controllers and views in play framework project when the project is created with scala option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to mix Java and Scala in a Play application. You can mix both Java and Scala controllers and  Groovy and Scala templates. The instructions below have been tested with Play! 1.2.2RC1.

I would start by keeping both your Java and Scala controllers in `app/controllers`. Java is of course limited to one class per file, but in Scala packages are not tied to files and directories, so you can give your Scala file any name; as long as you declare the package correctly as

```
package controllers
```

Play should have not trouble finding them.

Scala templates should end in `.scala.html` and Groovy templates in plain `.html`. In a Scala controller, you render Scala templates with `html.templatename` and Groovy templates with `Template("templatename").`

I have never tried rendering a Scala template from a Java controller, but I don't see why it should not be feasible.

Finally, here's a [useful reminder on Scala/Java interop](http://www.codecommit.com/blog/java/interop-between-java-and-scala).

Comment: Thanks. So it looks like scala file can be anywhere under app/controllers regardless of its package declaration. But Java files must follow directory structure according to the package.

Comment: Well I did not try java controller in scala project but I did try java class that is not a controller but like a service class but play hangs and does not work even if I just put the java file and not even being used.

Comment: That seems strange. Maybe it is better if you ask another question with a more detailed description of this problem (where exactly did you put that Java file?)